# How to take Screenshot in Mac OS X from inside of Python: aka Command-Control-Shift-4

Tags: python, macos

With Command-Control-Shift-4 the screenshot area can be taken/then saved to a clipboard.
I wonder if same would be possible from inside of Python. Ideally an image file format could be specified as well as to where to save it all programmatically within Python. Any ideas?

#### *edited later 1*

I've located `applescript` that does almost what's needed except this script captures an entire screen. I would like to limit it to a region instead.

```
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke (ASCII character 36) using {command down}
    delay 1
    keystroke space
end tell
```

#### *edited later 2*

The apple script below does a region screen capture quite well (there is still no control on to where exactly the captured image is saved (it is saved by default to the user's Desktop).

```
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke (ASCII character 36) using {command down}
    key code 4 using {command down, shift down}
end tell
```

The question is how to customize the output file path location...

Comment: `from PIL import ImageGrab
im = ImageGrab.grab()
im.save('screenshot.png')` Will get you the screenshot

Comment: I want to stay away from PIL. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: `import os os.system("screencapture screen.png")` Instead?

Comment: Cool! Any ideas on how to capture a screen region instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There seems to be a standard utility called `screencapture` on the Mac, you could use `subprocess` to call that, like so:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["screencapture", "screenshot.jpg"])
```

There are options to `screencapture` to specify a specific rectangle as well:

```
$ screencapture -h
. . . 
  -R<x,y,w,h> capture screen rect
```

Comment: Thank you! It looks like I ended up with the same solution. But yours is shorter. I am going to use it. Thanks again! It turned to be a flag to limit `screencapture` to a region is: `-i`

Comment: I am getting: `libpng warning: zero length keyword
libpng warning: Empty language field in iTXt chunk`...

Comment: I don't think you need applescript, this is just using the built-in shell.  If you run the command in a terminal, do you see the same libpng warning?  This page - https://discussions.apple.com/message/20691159#20691159 - seems to indicate that the errors are harmless (though irritating).

Comment: Thanks OldGeeks, I've just posted a line with -i flag in place. It works like a charm. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Mac users who experience difficulty getting these functions to work - namely, when you screen capture it only shows the desktop wallpaper - the reason is that you need to give permissions to relevant software (e.g. Terminal, PyCharm CE, etc.) you are using for the screen capture commands as found in System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Screen Recording.

Answer (score 0):

`/Users/MYNAME/` should be existent for example to work:

```
import subprocess

def runAppleScript(appleScript=None):   
    AppleProcess=subprocess.Popen(['osascript', '-'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    AppleProcess.communicate(appleScript)[0]

appleScript="""on run
    set shellCommand to "/usr/sbin/screencapture -i \\"" & "/Users/MYNAME/Pictures/Screenshot.png\\""
    do shell script shellCommand
end run"""

runAppleScript(appleScript)
```

Comment: You're using `Popen` to start a process to run AppleScript to start a process. Why not cut AppleScript out of it and start the `screencapture` process directly from Python?

Comment: `from subprocess import call; call(["screencapture", "-i", "/Users/user/Documents/screenshot.jpg"])`

Comment: Thanks guys for help! Posting the line I've ended up using. The `libpng warning` appears harmless and causes no discomfort. Very clean and sharp way to get things done. I like it a lot. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Following works well for me just by importing `from selenium import webdriver`:

```
self.now = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')
self.driver.save_screenshot('login-%s.png' % self.now)
```

It creates files in the same directory from where script was executed with time stamp.

Answer (score 0):

I find these these commands work for me on my Mac OS X

```
from subprocess import call

call(["screencapture", "screenshot.jpg"])   # Captures full screen
call(["screencapture", "-R 100,100,500,500", "screenshot.jpg"]) # Captures area of screen
```

The first call captures a full screen.
The second call captures a section of screen.
This screenshot.jpg is saved automatically in the directory the python code runs.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [PyObjC](https://pythonhosted.org/pyobjc/) to access [Quartz Window Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/CGWindow_Reference/Reference/Introduction.html), which can be used to create screenshots.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Daniel: Even if all the links were broken, this would still be a helpful answer; it directs the reader to the appropriate native API to be used for the purpose, and additionally provides a name for a way to access that native API from Python. The links make it more convenient to access the documentation for them, but are by no means essential.

Answer (score -1):

`screencapture -h` works perfectly for me.

```
$ screencapture -h . . . -R<x,y,w,h> capture screen rect

$ screencapture -R100,100,500,500 asdf.png
```

This line save a partial screenshot 400x400 pixels wide with file name asdf on the directory where i run the command.

Thanks oldgeeksguide