# Python, Pyautogui: Not possible to take ingame screenshots?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently trying to take screenshots of my game under specific circumstances. But every time I use `pyautogui.screenshot()` I only get a screenshot of my desktop. Is there any way you can change this to take in game screenshots ?

Edit: The game is 'Dota 2'

Comment: What is your game? Is it a program you created or is it a commercial product?

Comment: It is 'Dota 2', one of the most played games out there.

Comment: Is the window of fixed dimensions? Can you provide that screenshot of the full desktop?

Comment: Yes, the game is running on fullscreen (1920x1080). This is what a screenshot looks like, when my monitor is actually showing the game: http://abload.de/img/picture93rl4.png

Comment: Of the game please, not your program.

Comment: http://abload.de/img/gamejhkiu.jpg

Comment: Use the little gear as an image to locate.

Comment: `data = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('image.png')`

Comment: `pyautogui.screenshot(region = (x, y, 1920, 1080))`

Comment: I want my script to tell me, when a window opens in the game. So at first I used the `pyautogui.locateOnScreen()` but it couldnt detect the image. Then I changed it to take a screenshot to compare my image with the screenshot, and then i realized that it ignores my game.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue on a Mac and the problem might not be your code.  It can often be resolved by a simple fix in your security settings:

Mac users who experience difficulty getting screen capture functions to work - namely, when you screen capture it only shows the desktop wallpaper - the reason is that you need to give permissions to relevant software (e.g. Terminal, PyCharm CE, etc.) you might need to check the checkboxes for those programs using screen capture commands as found in System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Screen Recording.

If you are looking for alternative code to pyautogui look here: [How to take Screenshot in Mac OS X from inside of Python: aka Command-Control-Shift-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667794/)