# Taking a screenshot using Python on Linux

Tags: python, linux, macos, gtk

I am trying to take a screenshot through a python script. I have gone through both of these

https://stackoverflow.com/a/782768/7504076 and https://github.com/JDongian/neobot/blob/master/Linux/Robot/screen.py

Both run successfully, but on a couple of machines it just returns a black screen always. On some machines it returns perfect screenshots. I just don't seem to  understand what seems to be the problem.

I'm running only on Macs, but the problem is not confined to a particular OS version, as it runs on a couple of machines running El-Capitan and Sierra and also fails on machines running the same OS's.
Is it some system setting that should be changed or some parameter that I can change to get proper image.

Comment: Have you tried these answers? 1. [How to take Screenshot in Mac OS X from inside of Python: aka Command-Control-Shift-4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667794/how-to-take-screenshot-in-mac-os-x-from-inside-of-python-aka-command-control-sh) 2. [Take screenshot in Python on Mac OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524723/take-screenshot-in-python-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: @Nova Both of them work perfectly on all machines, but I need the same code if possible to work on other linux machines also... Any help on that?